# regex for removing code in php file

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I want to create a Regex for removing some huge php code (got hacked).

The code can be seen here
[click here for pastebin file](http://pastebin.com/NDFCMd7m)

what i've thought to remove is using this:

```
find /home \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.php" \) -exec sed -i.bak 's/<?php $oqwjihijbu = '($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]))))//g' \{\} \;
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what's intended, that regex will need to have its metacharacters escaped (i.e. `? $ [ ]`):

```
find /home \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.php" \) \
  -exec sed -i.bak \
   's/<\?php \$oqwjihijbu = \'(\$GLOBALS\["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"\]))))//g' {} \;
```

But even then you're only removing the bit of PHP code at the very beginning of the injected attack, and it looks like it will leave a file with malformed PHP that can't be run anyway. To remove the full attack code is almost certainly more than you can do with a single `sed` expression.

I'm afraid you're in a world of hurt here, and recommend that you'll be much better off wiping the webserver clean and reinstalling the site's code from scratch.

Comment: Hello Tim And thank you for your quick response,
As you said i only remove this little part of code:
<?php $oqwjihijbu = '($GLOBALS["%x61%156%x75%156%x61"]))))

But how can i remove the whole attack code is here
[link]http://pastebin.com/NDFCMd7m

Comment: I do not think you will be able to remove it with `sed`, which is not very effective at matching multiple lines of text at once. On top of that, you will be lucky if every injected file uses identical injected code. These attacks are often very skilled at infiltrating your site deeply. As I said, I think the most effective way of addressing this will be to reinstall the site from scratch.